# Ruby: Connect to remote WebSocket

Tags: ruby, websocket, celluloid

I'm trying to connect to remote websocket using Celluloid and Websocket client based on celluloid ([gem 'celluloid-websocket-client'](https://github.com/jeremyd/celluloid-websocket-client)). The main advantage of this client for me is that I can use callbacks in the form of class methods instead of blocks.

```
require 'celluloid/websocket/client'
class WSConnection
  include Celluloid

  def initialize(url)
    @ws_client = Celluloid::WebSocket::Client.new url, Celluloid::Actor.current
  end

  # When WebSocket is opened, register callbacks
  def on_open
    puts "Websocket connection opened"
  end

  # When raw WebSocket message is received
  def on_message(msg)
    puts "Received message: #{msg}"
  end

  # When WebSocket is closed
  def on_close(code, reason)
    puts "WebSocket connection closed: #{code.inspect}, #{reason.inspect}"
  end

end

m = WSConnection.new('wss://foo.bar')

while true; sleep; end
```

The expected output is

```
"Websocket connection opened"
```

However, I don't get any output at all. What could be the problem?

I am using

```
gem 'celluloid-websocket-client', '0.0.2'
rails 4.2.1
ruby 2.1.3
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting tot the websocket outside of your app? For instance from within browser console

Comment: @andHapp I tried both browser and traditional clients inside my app (like em-websocket) and it worked well

Comment: Actually, I found out, that close callback is working, but on_open and on_message are not

Comment: I've not had enough time lately to give the complete answer, but I want you to know I'm coming back to resolve this for you.

Comment: @digitalextremist thank you, I resolved it. The problem was with celluloid-websocket-client itself. It does not handle SSL Sockets correctly, I ve pushed pull commit https://github.com/jeremyd/celluloid-websocket-client/pull/15

Comment: I ran into this too. I came to answer with the SSL issue, and saw you noticed it. Do you mind answering your own question and accepting your answer? I watch the `celluloid` tag for unanswered questions and this is at the top right now :) Actually, I will submit an answer with a patch and also instructions on how to react to this in the future, once the library changes.

Comment: Posted a complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed in the comments, the gem had no `SSL` support. That is the trouble. To expound on the answer, here is a resolution, and also some next steps of what to expect for the future:

---

#### [ now ] Override methods in `Celluloid::WebSocket::Client::Connection`

This is an example injection to provide `SSL` support to the current gem. Mine is actually highly modified, but this shows you the basic solution:

```
def initialize(url, handler=nil)
  @url = url
  @handler = handler || Celluloid::Actor.current
  #de If you want an auto-start:
  start
end

def start
  uri = URI.parse(@url)
  port = uri.port || (uri.scheme == "ws" ? 80 : 443)
  @socket.close rescue nil
  @socket = Celluloid::IO::TCPSocket.new(uri.host, port)
  @socket = Celluloid::IO::SSLSocket.new(@socket) if port == 443
  @socket.connect
  @client = ::WebSocket::Driver.client(self)
  async.run
end
```

The above sends ripple effects through the other methods however, for example, `@handler` is used to hold the calling actor, which also has the emitter methods on it. Like I said, my version is very different from the stock gem because I got fed up with it and reworked mine. But then:

---

#### [ soon ] Use `Reel::IO::Client` and avoid near certain brain damage.

There are exciting things going on with `WebSocket` support, and a gem is coming to refactor both server and client implementations of websockets. No more monkeypatches required!

All websocket functionality is being extracted from `Reel` and being combined with a `websocket-driver` abstraction, as `Reel::IO`...  in both `::Server` and `::Client` varieties.

Interestingly, this is prompted by `Rails` which is moving away from `EventMachine` to `Celluloid::IO` for websockets:

- https://github.com/rails/actioncable/issues/16
- https://github.com/celluloid/reel/issues/201
- https://github.com/celluloid/reel-io/issues/2

> A prealpha is online for preview: https://github.com/celluloid/reel-io